# Numerically finding eigenvalues of a Volterra operator of first kind

Tags: numerical-linear-algebra, integral-equations

I'm looking for a solution to the following problem -

$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} K(x-y) f(y) = \lambda f(x)$

Consider $K(x-y) = \left\{ \begin{array}{lr} e^{-(x-y)} & : x > y \\ 0 & : x < y \end{array} \right.$

In this case, we can actually find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors analytically, since $f(x) = e^{i \omega x}$ is an eigenvector:

$\int_{-\infty}^x e^{-(x-y)} e^{i \omega y}  = \frac{e^{i \omega x}}{1 + i \omega}$

But now, if I try to do this numerically, i.e., if I discretize the integral: $\tilde{K}(x_i,y_j) = K(x_i - y_j)$, then I end up with a triangular matrix with 1's on the diagonal, and all the eigenvalues are thus 1.

I don't really see how to resolve this issue numerically, so any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What quadrature rule are you using?

Comment: I just use the trapezoidal rule with a large cut-off value. But I don't see how that would make a difference since the matrix is triangular and so without even implementing a numerical routine, the eigenvalues would all seem to be 1

Comment: If you are using a cutoff value, then you cannot choose discretization points near that cutoff value, because then the approximation will not be good. So your matrix should not be triangular in the traditional sense.

Comment: To be more explicit: There will be a band of 1s, but it should lie above the diagonal, not on it.

Comment: I think I see what you mean. Would there be a different way to proceed with such a problem numerically? This is warm-up for a more complicated problem involving matrix exponentials where an analytic solution isn't possible.

Comment: You could try discretizing with respect to a basis for which each integral can be computed exactly. You should also check if the operator is normal; if not then the eigenproblem is numerically unstable.

Comment: I should amend: *Potentially* unstable